# How to fix "Function name must be a String" error in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I have a database table called precios, with just 4 columns, the first column is called codigo. The idea is to compare the actual webpage name with the data in the codigo column. For example, my actual webpage name is called: ...AC01.php, in the table the column codigo contains a row AC01 with other columns with prices, so when PHP knows that the actual web page is AC01.php, will output the prices related to the row of the same name as the page in several parts of the web design. I'm trying to test this comparison before proceeding with the following steps.

This is my actual code:

```
$pageName=basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], ".php"); (tested, works!)
$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','%%%','%%%'); (tested, connection works!)

/*checking connection*/
if(mysqli_connect_errn()) {
   printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
   exit();
}

$query="SELECT * FROM precios WHERE codigo='$pageName'";
$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $row;

mysqli_close($link);
```

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Fatal error: Function name must be a string in ...AC01.php on line 40.
```

From Dreamweaver, I can see that line 40 is the following:

```
 $result=$mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: You have an extra `$` before `mysqli_query`. `$result=$mysqli_query($link, $query);` should be `$result=mysqli_query($link, $query);`.

Comment: While you're at it, please fix the [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability in your code, too. Rewrite the code with [MySQLi prepared statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), and save your website from being hacked.

Comment: Deleting the extra `$` before `mysqli_query` outputs the following: `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ...AC01.php on line 4`

Comment: I think the error message is pretty self-explanatory. `mysqli_fetch_array()` expects a MySQL result object, but it is receiving a boolean value instead. Where does it get that from? From `mysqli_query()` of course, because it returns a boolean value, depending on whether the query succeeded or not. What does that mean? It means your query probably failed. You need to use the error handling functions (`mysqli_error($link)`) and see what's wrong with the query. **Always check for return values, and assume failure.**

Comment: So `$result` is just saying: "I am true"... I see. Thank for helping me @AmalMurali

Comment: Not really, no. Check the [documentation for `mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) to see what values it returns (on success and on failure). You should always search before asking. All these error messages have been covered pretty well here on Stack Overflow, and on other sites — it's only a matter of finding it. In any case, please read [Ask] first. It has some helpful tips on how to ask a *good* question.

Comment: So you think the problem might be from the SQL statement ?

Comment: I did research this, believe me, however I will do more. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Why don't you just try what I said in my previous comment? (About using the available error functions such as `mysqli_error()`)

Comment: Trying with `echo mysqli_errno($link)` outputs `1046`.

Comment: or in other words: No database selected ...

Comment: Please read the comment again. This is what I said: "*You need to use the error handling functions (mysqli_error($link)) and see what's wrong with the query.*" — `mysqli_error()`, not `mysqli_errno`. Either way, the problem is that you're not selecting the database. Do that. Change `$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','%%%','%%%');` to **`$link=mysqli_connect('localhost','%%%','%%%', 'YOUR_DATABASE_NAME_GOES_HERE');`**.

Comment: `mysqli_error`outputs _No database selected_ this was very helpful because the database name was not set in the `$link`. Now adding the rest of the original code: `$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)` and `echo $row` outputs no more errors, just a text saying _Array_

Comment: Because `$row` is an array. Arrays can't be `echo`ed. You need to use `print_r()` or `var_dump()` instead. Or loop through the array using a  `foreach`.

Comment: @AmalMurali thank you for all your support.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
$result=$mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

is wrong. You need to remove the $ . So in your case it will be:

```
$result= mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: I did, please read all the comments of the original post. Thanks